# Como borrar un valor en una lista? en python

Tags: python

necesito crear un sistema que una vez elegido un asiento, borre este y ya no sea elegible, que podría usar para esto? intente usando `x = int(input("valor")` y luego usando `del(lista[x])` pero no me funciona.

```
print("Bienvenido a la aerolinea skyweta,para empezar, por favor indique si querra un asiento normal o vip") 
try: 
    opcion=int(input("en caso de querer un asiento normal con un valor de 78.900, marque 1,\n en caso de querer un asiento vip por 240.000, marque 2\n")) 
except: 
    print("Debe ingresar solo numeros del 1 al 2, por favor intente nuevamente\n")#Vuelve al while si el dato no es un numero 
if(opcion==1): 
    arreglo=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30] 
    try:
        x = int(input("Ingrese el numero de asiento que desea tomar\n")) 
        print(f"Su asiento es el numero {x}") 
        del(arreglo[{x}]) 
    except: 
        print("Debe ingresar solo numeros para escoger su asiento, por favor intente nuevamente\n") 
        del(arreglo[{x}]) 
        print(f"{arreglo}")
```

Comment: No sé cuál es la obsesión por usar `del`. Podrías compartir tu código completo, por favor, tal vez no es necesario eliminar el valor solo agregar un `if`

Comment: del es una función de  python, es como decir no sé cual es la obsesión de usar comprensión de listas. Que  no te guste o no la quieras usar no es para remarcarlo en otros.

Comment: ahi lo puse en respuestas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @tincopasan cada función se utiliza cuando es necesario, las listas tienen sus métodos `pop()` y `remove()`

Comment: si dices que no te funciona, agrega detalles de porque dices eso. Tienes algún error? el resultado no es el esperado?

Comment: @Christian más allá de los métodos propios de cada objeto, del se puede usar en muchos de ellos.

Comment: @matias estas utilizando mal la sintaxis para acceder a un elemento de la lista. No debes poner las llaves `{}` solo pon `del(arreglo[arreglo.index(x)])` con `index()` obtienes la posición del elemento

Comment: si eso usaba antes y tampoco funciona, lo que quiero es una funcion que elimine el valor de una lista si es que hay

Comment: @matias por favor tomate el trabajo de leer los enlaces que te pase y entender como funciona el sitio

Comment: @Christian por favor, no edites publicaciones de esa forma. Primero no sabemos si la identacion es la misma que tenia OP (importantisimo en python), luego, OP no aprende a usar el sitio de esa forma. Enseñale que hay un boton [edit] debajo de su publicacion donde puede arreglar su pregunta

Comment: @gbianchi lo siento, culpa mía.

Comment: ahora funciono, graciassss <33

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar tu sintaxis está mal, no debes de poner las llaves `{}` solo basta con `del(arreglo[x])` pero esto elimina el elemento que este en esa posición pero como le estas pasando un asiento, para eliminar el asiento deberías obtener su índice con `arreglo.index(x)` que obtiene el índice del elemento, quedando `del(arreglo[arreglo.indix(x)])` pero a mí me parece un poco confuso, por eso existe el método `remove()` que elimina un elemento según su valor (por esto digo que no siempre es conveniente usar `del`). Quedando.

```
arreglo.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

en realidad con lo que has puesto debería eliminar el elemento:

```
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
x = int(input("valor") )

del(lista[x])

print(lista)
```

lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que borra el elemento por su índice!

es decir si ingreso como valor 1 borrará ese índice de la lista:

```
valor : 1
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

como ves no es que elimine el 1 sino el elemento del índice 1

para completar, si lo que quieres es eliminar dado el número de asiento, debes tomar su posición en la lista:

```
pos=lista.index(x) 
del(lista[pos])
```